# Linked List not looping properly

Tags: c++, list

Here is my code:

```
void setUpEachFlechette(int numFlechettes){

int i = 0;
int totalNum = 0;

Flechette* next;
Flechette* head;
Flechette* pEnd;
Flechette* temp;

    while(numFlechettes != i){

        double x = getRandomNumberX();
        double y = getRandomNumberX();
        double z = getRandomNumberZ();


         if(i != 0)
          temp = next;

         next = new Flechette;

         next->setXYZ(x, y, z);

         if(i == 0)
            head = next;
         else
          next->link = temp;

         i++;

         next->display();

    }


 cout<<"\nThe total number of flechettes is "<<totalNum<<endl<<endl;

 char yes = NULL;

 cout<<"Ready? ";
 cin>>yes;

 i = 0;

 next->link = NULL;
 next = head;
 while(next != NULL){

    next->display();
    next = next->link;

    i++;

 }
```

}

For some reason, when I am looping through the linked list, it only is displaying the first 4 nodes in the list and it continues to repeat those first four. I also cannot get it to end on a null properly so i can run it through a while(next != null) loop. I was wondering how come my coding doesn't loop through all of the Flechettes? For a reference, it should loop through 20 different flechettes, not just 4 flechettes 'i' number of times.

I think the functions are pretty self explanatory. If they aren't let me know and I'll explain them to you.

Comment: The debugger is your friend. Use it to step through the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: I just started looking at the debugger. Gotta get into it some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not modifying variable `totalNum` before printing. Also i think the code should be like this

```
void setUpEachFlechette(int numFlechettes){

int i = 0;
int totalNum = 0;

Flechette* next;
Flechette* head;
Flechette* pEnd;
Flechette* temp;
srand (time(NULL));
    while(numFlechettes != i){

        int x = rand();
        int y = rand();
        int z = rand();


         if(i != 0)
          temp = next;

         next = new Flechette;

         next->setXYZ(x, y, z);

         if(i == 0)
            head = next;
         else
          temp->link = next;

         i++;

         next->display();

    }

totalNum = numFlechettes;
 cout<<"\nThe total number of flechettes is "<<totalNum<<endl<<endl;

 char yes;

 cout<<"Ready? ";
 cin>>yes;

 i = 0;

 next->link = NULL;
 next = head;
 while(next != NULL){

    next->display();
    next = next->link;

    i++;

 }
}
```

In your original code `head` node will be the last node and `head->next` will be `NULL`

I expect you are properly initializing member variable `link` with `NULL` inside the constructor of `Flechette`

Comment: If I change it to temp->link = next; it outputs the first node adn then the second nodex19

Comment: can you please explain 'then the second nodex19'... I expect your construtor and display functions are correct. Have you written a construtor for Flechette??

Comment: all I had for the constructor was Flechette::Flechette(){ link = NULL;}

Comment: And the output would display the first node correctly (the head one) and then it would show the second node 19 times in a row

Comment: please check my function. only modification is in random number generation. i am getting correct results. your Constructor is v fine.

Comment: I repasted what you posted into my code and it works perfectly ! Thank you very much, man!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle simple single-linked lists. One is to always add at the head of the list, and this is the simplest method:

```
struct Node
{
    Node* next;

    Node()
        : next(nullptr)  // Make sure the `next` pointer is not pointing anywhere
        {}
};

Node* head = nullptr;

while (add_one_more_node())
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;

    // Make the `next` point to the old head
    newNode->next = head;

    // Make the head point to the new node
    head = newNode;
}
```

The second way is to keep track of the last node in the list as well, and insert at the end. This is slightly more tricky:

```
// Assume `Node` structure as in above example

Node* head = nullptr;
Node* tail = nullptr;

while (add_one_more_node())
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;

    if (tail == nullptr)
    {
        // List is empty
        head = tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        // List is not empty

        // Make the current tails next link point to the new node
        tail->next = newNode;

        // Make the new node the next tail
        tail = newNode;
    }
}
```

With both ways, you can use the same loop to iterate over the list:

```
// Loop over the list
for (Node* node = head; node != nullptr; node = node->next)
{
    // ...
}
```

To free the list, you need a little more complicated loop, so you don't free the node before you get the next pointer:

```
for (Node* node = head, *next; node != nullptr; node = next)
{
    // Next node to iterate to
    next = node->next;

    // Free the current node
    delete node;
}
```